# JQuery scrollTo function error can't find a way to scroll to a certain div ID during on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to scroll to a certain section on on my website this section is marked with an ID and I want to do so using an animated jquery scroll on a click event.  This is my current code:

js header section

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Menu area

```html
<li><a onclick="scrollTo()" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a onclick="scrollTo()" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a onclick="scrollTo()" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a onclick="scrollTo()" href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Test")
    function scrollTo() {
        console.log("Clicked!")
        var elem = document.getElementById('testimonials');
        console.log(elem)
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
        window.scrollTo
    }
})
```

Comment: May be you want: element.scrollIntoView();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/YoKwYJ)

**Firstly : Don't use `scrollTo` for your handler name. because `scrollTo` is a function in js.**

---

Additional Steps:

1. Add inline events to your navigation elements like this:

```
<a onclick="scrollTo_(event,'testimonials')" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
```

It will pass `click event` and also an `id` to let the handler know what's the target element's id.

2. Handler function should be like this:

```
function scrollTo_(ev,id) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
  }, 2000);
}
```

It's using preventDefault to prevent normal `<a>` click behavior. and it use this answer ([how to animate scroll with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/4718434)) for animate scroll to element with jquery.

---

Additional notes:

- Don't put your function declarations inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Makes sense appreciated